# HTTP Content Type returned by server when a response is not required

Tags: http-headers

When returning html to the client, I set the server content type to:
    "text/html"

When I returning JSON to the client, I set the server content type to:
    "application/json"

I have a special case where the client makes an AJAX call to do something unimportant and the client really doesn’t benefit by getting a reply from the server so I just return an empty reply and set the server content type to:
    "application/json"

Is this OK even though my reply is empty?

Thank you

Comment: It depends. What kind of AJAX are you using? For instance, in JQuery, a client request specifies the format it wants the response to use - json, html, text, etc.

Comment: At this time I am not specifying the format during my jquery request, at least until I what content type should be used for my empty server reply.

Comment: Does the client know ahead of time that the reply will be empty? If so, then it does not really matter. But whatever format the client asks for, the server has to honor, even if it is blank. I would suggest picking a single format for all requests for consistency, if feasible.

Comment: The client does know that the reply will be empty because the AJAX call will not check the reply. I could have the server respond with something but I am guessing that it is just a waste since the client will not even examine it. Since the client sent some JSON, I figured the response from the server would be JSON as well even though it does not return JSON.